# Using react-native-community/datetimepicker, How Can I Display a time what user has selected instead taking from new date?

Tags: react-native

So problem is easy but still i dont get it what i am doing wrong.I am able to display time picker in IOS also its working fine it taking time from new date .But i dont want that ,my app demands whenever user clicks on button picker comes and display time what i am sending like if i am sending 21 it should come 9 00 PM .

Here's my code:

```
const app = props => {

 const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
 const [time, setTime] = useState();

 const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


 const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
 const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
 setShow(Platform.OS === "ios");
 setDate(currentDate);
};

//In selectedTime i am getting object which is like {"Hour": 15,"Minute": 0}
const showTimepicker = selectedTime => {
setTime(selectedTime.Hour ? new Date(selectedTime.Hour) : new Date());
setShow(true);
};

const onClickCancel = () => {
setShow(false);
};

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View>
    <DateTimePicker
      testID="dateTimePicker"
      value={time}
      mode="time"
      is24Hour={true}
      display="spinner"
      onChange={onChange}
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      textColor="black"
      themeVariant="light"
    />
  </View>
</View>
);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the `is24Hour` prop `false`.

```js
const time = new Date();
time.setHours(21);

<View style={styles.container}>
  <View>
    <DateTimePicker
      testID="dateTimePicker"
      value={time} // This will select current time. (Set your desired hours in your new Date() object in order to get the required time.)
      mode="time"
      is24Hour={true} // Make it false.
      display="spinner"
      onChange={onChange}
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      textColor="black"
      themeVariant="light"
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: no its showing 5.30 am it should show 9 becz i am sending 21. ,  value={time} here time is 21 that i am sending .

Comment: I don't think that just 21 is a correct value!

Comment: yeah i also but then what format its expecting?

Comment: I'm taking a look at its documentation and I think it expects a date object instead of a number.

Comment: i get it but how shud i send new Date() with time 21

Comment: I have updated the answer please check it.